# Could not load RNOneSignal native module. Make sure native dependencies are properly linked

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am attempting to set up OneSignal on my React-Native application. I have followed the steps [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup) precisely.

My question is:
If I am using an Android Emulator (and I understand that the push notifications will not work), is this the cause of the error? Or is this error unrelated to using the emulator with push notifications.

And if it is unrelated, what can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: You got to rebuild your app. For bare RN `npm run android`. For expo managed workflow follow this procedure https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-expo-sdk-setup